# Setting Source.list and installing lsb modules

Tags: software-sources, source, lsb-release

I wanted to set up my source list for ROS (Robotic Operation System) using this :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release
-sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

However I get this **error:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
sh: 2: -sc: not found
```

So i went to install the lsb modules using :

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

but got this **error:**

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)
```

This the output of lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

So I went to check the source file and tried to repair it following this instructions of this website : [see here](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/etc-apt-sources-list-ubuntu-16-xenial/)

and i got this **error** when i tried to replace and save the new source.list:

```
(gedit:3947): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

This is the source.list with the new content:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

and updating the source list, shows the same error as for installing the lsb modules.

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Could you add the contents of your sources.list here?

Comment: What command did you execute originally?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command should have been one line:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Since this overwrites the `ros-latest.list` file, you can just run the corrected command. It will overwrite the original incorrect lines.

Comment: Thank you! but i still get this error when i try to install lsb-core :

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-kinetic.list (Component)

Comment: Where did `ros-kinect.list` come from? Your post only mentions `ros-latest.list`.

Comment: it changed after i have used the correct command.

Comment: Then you can try deleting that file `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-kinetic.list`.